# Why does const not work even if the variable is not changed?

Tags: c, constants

I'm trying to protect the -a- array of the my_sum_array function from the changes. In the function block I do not make any changes to -a-, but I have a warning (warning: assignment to 'int *' from 'const int *' discards the qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]). I know I could remove const to make the program work, but I would like to understand if something is missing from me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

int my_sum_array(const int a[], int n);

int main(void) {
    int values[5] = {4, 7, 1, 7, 8};

    printf("The sum in my_sum_array is :%d\n", my_sum_array(values, MAX));

    return 0;
}

int my_sum_array(const int a[], int n) {
    int *p, sum = 0;

    for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        sum += *p;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You need to _add_ const somewhere. Look at the type of `p` in your function.

Comment: The problem is that merely creating an `int *` gives the rest of the code **license** to modify the data, even if the (current) implementation of the function doesn't do so. Consider what would happen if you passed `p` to a function accepting `int *` defined in another compilation unit. The compiler would then have no way to check that the data is not being modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type of `p` to:

```
const int *p;
```

So now you end up with:

```
const int * p;
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: @Mat Why would it fail?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is caused by the assignment `p = a` in the `for` loop. The variable is defined as `int *p`, a pointer to **non-const `int`**. The warning is correct, "assignment to `int *` from `const int *` discards the qualifiers". It's as though you've casted away the constness of the `a` pointer parameter.

I'd change your function to:

```
int my_sum_array(const int a[], int n) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (const int *p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        sum += *p;

    return sum;
}
```

This defines `p` as a pointer-to-const, just like `a`, and also limits its lifetime to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `p` pointer as:

```c
    int const * p;
```

i.e.

> here, `p` is a **pointer** to a **const integer**