# Does the address of a pointer (&ptr) change when reassigned (*ptr = n)? Why doesn't C allow const pointer (const int**) to non-const (int**) pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c) question, the example used is:

```
int       *      *x = NULL;
int       *const *y = x; /* okay */
int const *const *z = y; /* warning */
```

Where `int const *const *z = y; /* warning */` compiles with warning `'int const *const *' with an expression of type 'int *const *' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types`. The answer links to [Question 11.10 in the comp.lang.c FAQ.](https://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)

I am getting a similar warning when attempting to do:

```
char *x = strstr(...)
const char **z = &x;
```

But, after reading the answers & the FAQ, I still don't understand why the compiler discards the `const` qualifier. From what I remember, `*x = ...` does not affect `&x` and `&x` remains constant until x is reassigned (`x = ...`).

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783606/why-does-const-not-work-even-if-the-variable-is-not-changed) post, the warning makes sense because there is non-const pointer to const, however I don't understand why there is a warning in this case.

Comment: A variable can never change its location. `&x` will never change value.

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what the two `const` qualifiers in your declaration of `z` mean. In your code, `z` is a `const` pointer to a `const int*` but `y` is a `const` pointer to a non-const `int*`. Thus, the pointed-to types are different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then why would `const char **z = &x` be incorrect? If `&x` is constant

Comment: There's likely a duplicate around, somewhere. But try `int *const *const z = y;`. Actually, the question you've linked to is the duplicate ... not sure what to do about this one.

Comment: `y` is declared as a pointer to a `const char *`. While `&x` is a pointer to a `char *`. That's not really the same. If you want to emphasize that `*y` is constant (which it effectively is, since you can't modify `&x`) then use `char * const * y`. That means `*y` is constant. If you want `y` itself to be constant (not possible to assign to `y`) then use `char * const * const y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following code:

```
char *p = strdup("bark");
const char **dp = &p;
```

Compiling and running with `gcc in.c -o out.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wpedantic`:

```
warning: initialization of ‘const char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
const char **dp = &p;
                  ^
```

The warning message is clear: the two pointers are of incompatible types. To understand why this is problematic, try and modify the content of `p` via `dp`:

```
char *p = strdup("bark");
const char **dp = &p;
**dp = 'd';
```

Compile and run with the same command:

```
warning: initialization of ‘const char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
const char **dp = &p;
                  ^
error: assignment of read-only location ‘**dp’
**dp = 'd';
     ^
```

The `const` in `const char **dp` applies to the content at which `*dp` is pointing to, namely `p` (which is non-`const`). That's why you see the incompatibility warning message.

---

Now, try and do:

```
char *p = strdup("bark");
const char **dp = &p;
*dp = strdup("dark");
```

The code compiles just fine (with the above warning). However, changing the above code to

```
char *p = strdup("bark");
char *const *dp = &p;
*dp = strdup("dark");
```

Will produce the following error:

```
error: assignment of read-only location ‘*dp’
*dp = strdup("dark");
    ^
```

Unlike in `const char **dp`, the `const` in `char *const *dp` applies to the pointer at which `dp` is pointing to, namely `&p`. Therefore, changing it is not allowed.

Note that, in this same case, `**dp = 'd';` will compile just fine (with the above warning).

---

You can go further and try:

```
char *p = strdup("bark");
const char *const *dp = &p;
*dp = strdup("dark"); // Error
**dp = 'p';           // Error
```

```
warning: initialization of ‘const char * const*’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
const char *const *dp = &p;
                      ^
error: assignment of read-only location ‘*dp’
*dp = strdup("dark");
    ^
error: assignment of read-only location ‘**dp’
**dp = 'x';
     ^
```

---

Maybe writing the syntax differently will make things clearer:

1. `const char **dp == (const char)* *dp`
2. `char *const *dp == const (char*) *dp`
3. `const char *const *dp == const (const char)* *dp`

Comment: `**dp = 'd';` has nothing to do with the warning – fully clear that the assignment cannot happen as `**dp` is const, similarly the second example as you try to modify the const pointer `*dp`, while you entirely overlooked the real problem the warning arises from: `char* p /* no assignment needed...*/; char const** dp = &p; /* the critical point */; char const ca[] = "hello";` – as `ca` decays to a pointer to `char const` you can totally legally assign it to `*dp` – however `dp` points to a pointer to *non-const* char, thus with `*dp = ca;` you actually do

Comment: `x /* char* (!) */ = ca /* decays to char const* (!) */`; and are now able to modify the `const ca` via the pointer to non-const `p`. Next to the same problem existing in C++ you there have an equivalent problem with co- and contravariant function arguments or containers (polymorphism involved) where you wouldn't drop the const, but would be able to assign incompatible pointer types via a pointer to common base – which is why co- and contravariance with function arguments or containers are not allowed (while co-variant return types are legal).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
char*        x = ...;
char const** z = &x;

char const*  y = ...
```

`y` can point to an array that's truely const (non-writable memory). `y` is compatible to the declaration of `z`, so you could do:

```
*z = y;
```

Now, though, `x` – which `z` points to – has been (legally from point of view of `z`) assigned a `const` (non-writable) array you might try to modify via the `x` pointer (undefined behaviour)!

This is why the assignment of `x` to `z` is problematic, and this is why you get a warning issued, though admittedly the warning *text* could be a bit more precise. You consider it as in a way discarding the `const`-ness of the *target* of `z` by assigning a non-const pointer `x`...

Comment: OP's question is about why his last code snippet is producing a warning.

Comment: @Zakk And that's exactly what I'm referring to – note the pointer types! Though need to admit that I swapped variable names (fixed, now z as is while y newly introduced – in context of second code snipped, unfortunately x, y, z exist in both snippets...).